# Which relation to use in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Which relation to use in Laravel to bind two table through third?

When `Doctor`s can be assigned to some `Center`s. The intermediate table will be as:

```
doctor_id | center_id
```

How to create model in Laravel for this case?

Comment: Seems it is many -to many, is it necessery to build model in Laravel?

Comment: Using `attach()` and `detach()` will work in most use cases, but just in case you really do need a model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many Check the section called `Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models`

Comment: Please check this link. https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Hope the same scenario you want to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a model for the intermediate table, simply use attach

Example:

```php
$center = Center::create();
$doctor = Doctor::find(1);
$doctor->centers()->attach($doctor->id);
```

This is a very simple example but should give you the idea, of how to approach it.

All of it of course requires you have set up your Center and Doctor model with the correct many to many relations

**Doctor.php** model:

```php
public function centers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Doctor::class);
}
```

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships), for more information.

You could obviously create a model called DoctorsCenter and create it manually by doing this, whenever you want to attach a relation.

```php
DoctorsCenter::create(['center_id' => $center->id, 'doctor_id' => $doctor->id]);
```

I don't see any good reason for doing this, and would not recommend it.

Comment: @OPV can you explain a bit more in depth what you mean? I'm not sure I'm following.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **hasMany** or **belongsTo** relationship of Laravel.
See the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many), for more information

Comment: It's worth noting that `hasMany` is for one-to-many relationships, which doesn't apply to this case where there's a many-to-many relationship linked by an intermediate pivot table.